# Querying XML with XElement and .Element

Tags: xml, vb.net

Apologies for a really beginner question; I am very new to using VB with XML and need some guidance in order to reach a critical mass of understanding.

Given the following XML that describes various candies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Candy ID="MnMs">
    <Form ID="tablet" Name="Tablet">
      <Component ID="shell" Ingredients="sugar"/>
      <Component ID="filling" Ingredients="chocolate"/>
    </Form>
    <Form ID="oblong">
      <Component ID="shell" Ingredients="sugar"/>
      <Component ID="filling" Ingredients="chocolate"/>
      <Component ID="center" Ingredients="nut"/>
    </Form>
  </Candy>
  <Candy ID="LBalls">
    <Form ID="sphere">
      <Component ID="shell" Ingredients="chocolate"/>
      <Component ID="filling" Ingredients="chocolate ganache"/>
    </Form>
  </Candy>
  <Candy ID="RPieces">
    <Form ID="tablet">
      <Component ID="shell" Ingredients="sugar"/>
      <Component ID="filling" Ingredients="peanut butter ganache"/>
    </Form>
  </Candy>
</xs:schema>
```

(Note the use of `ID` rather than the more typical (recommended?) `id`.)

How, in VB, would I access the `Ingredients` attribute for `<Component>` RPieces/tablet/filling? Specifically, this line:

```
<Component ID="filling" Ingredients="peanut butter ganache"/>
```

My VB function follows; I am confused as to just how the identities are managed, especially given that the attributes are `ID` versus `id`.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml
...
Function CandyFetch(ByVal candyId As String, ByVal formId As String, ByVal compId As String, ByVal attrId As String, Optional ByVal docPath As String = "Candies.xml") As String
    Const ID = "ID"
    Dim result = ""
    docPath = docPath.Trim()
    If Not File.Exists(docPath) Then docPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + docPath
    For Each bonbon In XElement.Load(docPath).Elements("Candy")
        If bonbon.Attribute(ID).Value = candyId Then
            For Each form In bonbon.Elements("Form")
                If form.Attribute(ID).Value = formId Then
                    For Each component In form.Elements("Component")
                        If component.Attribute(ID).Value = compId Then
                            result = component.Attribute(attrId).Value
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
    Return result
End Function
```

Thank you.

Piling on, is there a simpler way to do this using LinqToXml and not have to iterate through the XML elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With LINQ to Xml it can look like below

```
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(docPath)
Dim value = doc.Descendants("Candy").
                Where(Function(candy) candy.Attribute("ID").Value = "RPieces").
                SelectMany(Function(candy) candy.Elements("Form")).
                Where(Function(form) form.Attribute("ID").Value = "tablet").
                SelectMany(Function(form) form.Elements("Component")).
                Where(Function(component) component.Attribute("ID").Value = "filling").
                Select(Function(component) component.Attribute("Ingredients").Value).
                FirstOrDefault()
```

By using LINQ to Xml with Xml Axis properties you can make code little bid simpler.
[XML Attribute Axis Property (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384755.aspx)

```
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(docPath)
Dim value = doc...<Candy>.
               Where(Function(candy) candy.@<ID> = "RPieces").
               <Form>.
               Where(Function(form) form.@<ID> = "tablet").
               <Component>.
               Where(Function(component) component.@<ID> = "filling").
               Select(Function(component) component.@<Ingredients>).
               FirstOrDefault()
```

If you import namespace to the code you will get Intellisense help for writing elments/attirbutes names for axis properties

Another approach is using serialization, create classes which represents structure of your xml, then your code will look as below

```
Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(YourRootClass))
Dim data As YourRootClass = Nothing
Using fileStream As New FileStream(docPath, FileMode.Open)
    data = serializer.Deserialize(fileStream)
End Using

Dim value = data.Candies.
                 Where(Function(candy) candy.ID = "RPieces").
                 SelectMany(Function(candy) candy.Forms).
                 Where(Function(form) form.ID = "tablet").
                 SelectMany(Function(form) form.Components).
                 Where(Function(component) component.ID = "filling").
                 Select(Function(component) component.Ingredients).
                 FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using XPATH queries:

```
Dim filename As String = "C:\Junk\example.xml"
Dim xdc As New XmlDocument
xdc.Load(filename)
Dim nsm As New XmlNamespaceManager(xdc.NameTable)
nsm.AddNamespace("xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")
Dim strXPATH As String = "/xs:schema/Candy[@ID=""RPieces""]/Form/Component[@ID=""filling""]/@Ingredients"
MsgBox(strXPATH & "=" & vbCrLf &
       xdc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(strXPATH, nsm).InnerText)
```

Comment: Still a beginner, here ... just Dim strXML = File.ReadAllText(docPath) to load the text from an external file? ...or should I be using XDocument.Load or something like that?

Comment: You can use `XmlDocument.Load` to load a file rather than parse an in-memory `String`. I have updated my answer